# Variable pattern matching awk

Tags: unix, awk

I have an input file "`myfile`" and a shell variable "`VAR`" whose
contents are shown below:

```
# cat myfile
Hello World
Hello Universe
# echo $VAR
World
```

I need to process all lines in "myfile" which contains pattern "World"
using awk. It works if i do as shown below:

```
# awk '/World/ { print $0 }' myfile
```

But i could not use VAR to do the same operation. I tried the
following even knowing that these will not work:

```
# awk '/$VAR/ { print $0 }' myfile
```

and

```
# awk -v lvar=$VAR '/lvar/ { print $0 }' myfile
```

and

```
# awk -v lvar=$VAR 'lvar { print $0 }' myfile
```

Please let me know how to match the contents of VAR in awk.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
awk -v lvar="$VAR" '$0~lvar {print}' myfile
```

Or (works but not recommended):

```
awk "/$VAR/ {print}" myfile
```

Comment: Its recommended not to use variable inside the `awk`, so I would have used the second one. Or like this `awk '$0~lvar {print}' lvar="$VAR" myfile`

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you want:

```
awk -v lvar="$VAR" '$0~lvar' myfile
```

Never do

```
awk "/$VAR/" myfile
```

or any other syntax that expands shell variables inline within the awk script such that they become part of the script as it can produce all sorts of bizarre failures and error messages depending on how the shell variable is populated since with that syntax there is no variable inside awk but the shell variable contents are instead integrated into the script as if you'd hard-coded it.

Always do the above using `-v` or

```
awk 'BEGIN{lvar=ARGV[1]; delete ARGV[1]} $0~lvar' "$VAR" myfile
```

depending on your requirements for the shell expanding backslashes. See http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24 for details.

Only do

```
awk '$0~lvar' lvar="$VAR" myfile
```

if you are processing multiple files, need to change initial values of the variable between files, and do not have gawk for `BEGINFILE` or need to populate those values from environment variables.

Note that all of the above do a regexp match on `lvar`, if you need a string match instead than use `awk -v lvar="$VAR" 'index($0,lvar)'`.

Answer (score 0):

If you export your variable, it becomes a simpler solution:

```
export VAR
awk '$0~ENVIRON["VAR"]' myfile
```

Takes out any issues of reprocessing the variable's value.